# Как сохранить сообщение(текст) пользователя в переменную на языке Java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, бот

Хотел бы сохранить текст который вводить пользователь моего бота в переменной типа String

```
 public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")

    Message message = update.getMessage();

    YearDefImpl yearDef1 = new YearDefImpl();

    if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
        switch (message.getText()) {
            case "/start":
                sendMsg(message, "Добрый день, выберите валюту");
                break;
            case "All Time":
                sendMsg(message, "Введите дату в формате \n" + formatdate.format(new Date()));
                break;
            case "USD":
                try {
                    sendMsg(message, yearDef1.year());
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[.]");// здесь проверяется на наличие ввода цифр
                Matcher m = p.matcher(message.getText());
                boolean b = m.matches();

                yearDef1.setString(message.getText()); //тут присваиваю полученный текст от пользователя
                try {
                    sendMsg(message, yearDef1.year());
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Не могу сохранить отправленный текст пользователем в переменную что бы использовать данную переменную в методе year().

Comment: эм, String в чем-то не подходит?

Comment: переменная не заполняется - null

Comment: в каком месте??

Comment: скорее всего подходит, может не правильно получаю текст пользователя )

Comment: yearDef1.setString(message.getText()); //тут присваиваю полученный текст от пользователя - в этом месте

Comment: YearDefImpl это ваш класс? гугл такого не находит

Comment: да это мой класс(сам придумал название)

Comment: Т.к. неизвестно что делает ваш метод ``setString``, то нельзя сказать что-то определенное. Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартными способами?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста стандартный способ, мне главное использовать смс пользователя т.е получить текст для переменной

Comment: Если ``message.getText()`` возвращает строку, то ``text = message.getText()``.

Answer (score 0):

Так получилось

```
 default:
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[.]");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(message.getText());
                boolean b = m.matches();
                b: // это была грубейшая ошибка (:)
                try {
                    yearDef1.setString(message.getText());
                    sendMsg(message, yearDef1.year());
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```